# I have a lot of SQL code that helps to model some data graphically, is there a way to easily convert this code to Python?

Tags: python, sql

I am currently working with a code-base that has thousands of lines of SQL code. The logic is correct however the code will need to be converted to Python.

Is there an easy way to convert this code to Python while maintaining the SQL logic/functionality?

I've looked into SQlalchemy but not too sure if this is the optimal approach.

Thanks

Small example SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT sale_date, store_state,

sum(sale_amount) as total_sales

FROM customers

GROUP BY store_state, sale_date

ORDER BY sale_date ASC;
```

Googled: "Convert SQL to Python". some advice said to use Pandas, others SQLalchemy.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example").

Answer (score 0):

If your logic *already consists of* "SQL code that already works," then I recommend that you use Python code which simply executes those SQL queries "directly, as written," and returns a recordset that you can then iterate. In this case, you do not need to concern yourself with libraries which endeavor to "dynamically construct SQL queries for you." Instead, you simply need to directly execute what you already have.

Comment: Thanks. How is that done? I googled this and every article I've seen comes up with SQLite3 and PyODBC and some "cursor" and execute. Is there a better way to perform this?